# Synonym request: [tcpip] --> [tcp]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[tcp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tcp) and [tcpip](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tcpip) are the same thing, right?

Can we make [tcpip](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tcpip) a synonym for [tcp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tcp), for clarity?

Comment: How many of those questions actually refer to TCP, and how many refer to IPv4? Someone should go through and retag these before this is done.

Answer (score 4):

I think [tcpip](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tcpip)  is a poor choice for a tag name. I would even say the term TCPIP should in general be avoided.

Sometimes the term TCPIP is used by people talking about the entire protocol suite including those things unrelated to TCP. In those cases "The IP protocol suite" or just "IP" for short would be better terms to use.

Sometimes the term TCPIP is used by people who don't really understand the boundaries between the different protocols. And I have seen people use it, when they actually should have said UDP.

Anybody specifically talking about TCP and knowing the distinction between the various protocols in the protocol suite would be more likely to simply say TCP than saying TCPIP.

So making [tcpip](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tcpip) a synonym for [tcp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tcp) is probably going to have a lot of questions tagged as [tcp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tcp) which shouldn't have been so. I think it would be better to make it a synonym for IP protocol suite or something to that effect.